# Cannot update fieldArray elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik

I'm trying to create a dynamic form using React.js and Formik library. The problem is that I cannot update services array except for the first array element.

My form model looks like:

```
{
    name: ''
    services: [{ name: '', comment: '' }],
}
```

My form must have an array of services with two fields (name and comment). Service names are generated as the radio buttons from the specific list. Here is the code:

```
<FieldArray
        name="services"
        render={arrayHelpers => (
          <div>
            {values.services.map((serviceX, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                {serviceList.map((service, serviceIndex) => (
                  <div className="col col--md-4" key={serviceIndex}>
                    <div className="radio--container">
                      <input
                        name={`services.${index}.name`}
                        type="radio"
                        id={service.label}
                        value={
                          services
                            ? services.find(
                                service => service.value === values.services[index].name
                              )
                            : ''
                        }
                        checked={service.value === values.services[index].name}
                        onChange={() =>
                          setFieldValue(
                            `services.${index}.name`,
                            service.value
                          )
                        }
                        onBlur={handleBlur}
                      />
                      <label htmlFor={service.label}>{service.label}</label>

                      <div className="check">
                        <div className="inside" />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}

                <Field name={`services.${index}.comment`} />
                <button
                  type="button"
                  onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(index)}
                >
                  -
                </button>
              </div>
            ))}
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push({ name: '', comment: '' })}
            >
              +
            </button>
          </div>
        )}
      />
```

I have also tried to make a separate stateless component for generating service list (radio buttons) but got the same results. However, using separate stateless component I noticed that index value (received from props) is different in DOM compared to component.

Comment: Not enough details. What are all these variables that you are using there?

Comment: You are missing key to div element inside serviceList.map

Comment: serviceList is just an array of objects with value & label fields. For instance: serviceList = [{value: 1, label: '1st'}, {value: 2, label: '2nd.'}] @DanielHilgarth

Comment: @Think-Twice Same result after adding key to container div.

Comment: My answer is not fix for your issue but a hint to add key to inner loop as well. It would be good if you can share complete component code

Comment: I don't think you want to see a class declaration as well as imports as well.